# Vue.js: Collapse/expand all elements from parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to add "expand/collapse all" functionality for my Vue component(some collapsible panel).

If user clicks collapse button then clicks on some panel and expand it then clicking on collapse button **will do nothing** because watched parameter will not change.

So how to implement this functionality properly (buttons must collapse and expand components always)?

I prepared simple example(sorry for bad formatting, it looks nice in editor :( ):

```js
var collapsible = {
  template: "#collapsible",
  props: ["collapseAll"],
  data: function () {
      return {
        collapsed: true
    }
  },
  watch: {
   collapseAll: function(value) {
     this.collapsed = value
    }
  }
}

var app = new Vue({
 template: "#app",
  el: "#foo",
  data: {
      collapseAll: true
  },
  components: {
   collapsible: collapsible
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper + .wrapper {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.header {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

.collapsible {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo"></div>


<script type="text/x-template" id="collapsible">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header" v-on:click="collapsed = !collapsed"></div>
    <div class="collapsible" v-show="!collapsed"></div>
 </div>
</script>


<script type="text/x-template" id="app">
 <div>
    <button v-on:click="collapseAll = true">Collapse All</button>
    <button v-on:click="collapseAll = false">Expand All</button>
   <collapsible v-for="a in 10" v-bind:collapseAll="collapseAll" v-bind:key="a"></collapsible>
  </div>
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think your example is great. Thank you for doing that; it really helps to understand the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a case where I might use a `ref`.

```
<button v-on:click="collapseAll">Collapse All</button>
<button v-on:click="expandAll">Expand All</button>
<collapsible ref="collapsible" v-for="a in 10" v-bind:key="a"></collapsible>
```

And add methods to your Vue.

```
var app = new Vue({
    template: "#app",
  el: "#foo",
  methods:{
    collapseAll(){
      this.$refs.collapsible.map(c => c.collapsed = true)
    },
    expandAll(){
      this.$refs.collapsible.map(c => c.collapsed = false)
    }
  },
  components: {
    collapsible: collapsible
  }
});
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MmzzvY?editors=1010).

Comment: Thanks! This solution is more elegant than mine (with child $emit on panel click).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work if the component is recursive. Is this due to ref not being reactive?

Comment: @PeterT sorry maybe it is not actual question already but in this fiddle I changed example to show recursive collapsing https://jsfiddle.net/maxsinev/q6cn3g7z/

Answer (score 0):

An example for reference,use vue@3.3.4

```js
<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";
const data=ref({
  list_1:{
    data:[1,2,3],
    is_expand:true
  },
  list_2:{
    data:[4,5,6],
    is_expand:true
  }
})
</script>
<template >
  <div>
  <div v-for="(v,k) in data">
    <label @click="v.is_expand=!v.is_expand">{{k}}</label>
    <div v-for="i in v.data" class="min-item" v-show="v.is_expand">
    <input type="checkbox"><div>{{i}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</template>

<style scoped>
  .min-item{
    display: flex;
  }
</style>
```

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).